# Using the cigar lighter outlet to power a small 1,000 lbs winch

Tags: electrical

Can I run a 1000 lbs winch through  the 12 volt cigar lighter of my truck or is it asking too much from the outlet? The wires are heavy gauge.

Comment: If the supplied wires are heavier gauge than the wires supplying power to the cigarette lighter then I wouldn't trust the connection to supply sufficient amperage reliably. The best problem would be a blown fuse; cigarette lighter type connections are always fused. There's a big difference between running a winch with no load and running it at its limit pulling capacity.

Comment: Short answer, No.

Comment: Don’t do this, if you do you will be lucky if you only blow a fuse.

Comment: Forgot to ask. Did the winch come with a fused cigarette lighter connector or you going to splice one in?

Comment: @SolarMike - People plug coffee makers into their cigarette lighters all the time (a practise I abhor btw). Anything involving heat to boil water uses much more power than a small DC motor geared down to supply a lowly 1000lb pull.

Comment: @Jeeped those water heaters have resistance such that they boil water in 5 minutes or so... the current needed for a winch is greater by a factor of probably 100...

Comment: lighter is usually just a 8-12-amp fuse. What's the amperage of your winch

Comment: @SolarMike - A car coffee machine typically draws ~100W or 8.6A @ 12V at peak; a 1000 lb ATV/Utility winch will typically have a 12V/1HP motor which draws 8-9A. Given that you canu usually winch an ATV into a pickup's bed faster that making two cups of coffee, I find the situation plausible. However, the OP has not supplied enough information (amperage, typical load, etc) to make a defined determination.

Comment: @Jeeped 1hp is 746W, 746W / 12 is 62A so not sure how you get 8 or 10A unless you did not have 1hp in the first place.

Comment: @SolarMike - Goodbye. It was nice seeing your name as a salutation to intelligent comments.

Comment: @Jeeped Et tu Bruté.

Answer (score 1):

Since you really didn't provide any specifications for the motor in the 1000 lb winch you are looking at, I had to do my own research and figure out if what you are asking is feasible. I can tell you without a doubt, it's not.

Here's why ...

I found a few marine winches rated at 1000 lb, but the lowest otherwise was 1500 lb typically used in the automotive realm. That said, the marine winch had a motor which is rated at 1000w. 1000w @ 12vdc equates to 83.3A, which far exceeds the 15A capacity (nominal) of your cigarette lighter outlet. Even the 1500 lb winch with a 70A motor exceeds this. If you want to run this winch in your vehicle, it needs to be direct wired to the battery with the appropriate size of inline fuse for protection.

For future use, to figure out how many watts of power your cigarette lighter outlet can provide, find the fuse for it, which should be in the fuse panel inside the passenger compartment. Once you find the rating for this fuse in Amps, multiply this number by the voltage of the vehicle (usually 12vdc nominal), which will give you the watts. For reference on a 12vdc electrical system:

- 15A = 180W
- 20A = 240W

Neither one is ANYWHERE close to being able to provide you the power you need to operate a winch. (NOTE: I'm showing the watts here in case the motor you are using states watt usage instead of Amps. You now have both pieces of knowledge in your arsenal.)

Comment: Thank you very much Sir, your expertise is much appreciated. What I've done since in to add a battery to the set up and connected the battery to the 12 V. output to keep her charged. Although I've not tried it yet, what do you think of the setup?

Comment: @MarioHamel - Look on here for questions about similar setups ... there are some considerations.